# Splitting an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of arrays that looks like this.

```js
const data = [
    ['list1'],
    ['item1', '1'],
    ['item2', '2'],
    ['item3', '3'],
    ['item4', '4'],
    [' ']
    ['list2'],
    ['item1', '1'],
    ['item2', '2'],
    ['item3', '3'],
    ['item4', '4'],
    [' ']
    ['list3'],
    ['item1', '1'],
    ['item2', '2'],
    ['item3', '3'],
    ['item4', '4'],
    [' ']
]
```

I need to get all of the items between the list1, list2 & list3 and the empty value to build a more structured container so that list1, list2 & list3 include the items as children. e.g.
{

```js
const data2 = {
    'list1': {'item1': '1', 'item2': '2', 'item3': '3', 'item4': '4'},
    'list2': {'item1': '1', 'item2': '2', 'item3': '3', 'item4': '4'},
    'list3': {'item1': '1', 'item2': '2', 'item3': '3', 'item4': '4'},
    'list4': {'item1': '1', 'item2': '2', 'item3': '3', 'item4': '4'}
}
```

Whats the most efficient way to query the data array to get the items between the list headers? I see lodash has a `_.slice` method which takes an index but I can't see a way to use the value of the array as a delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const data = [
  ['list1'],
  ['item1', '1'],
  ['item2', '2'],
  ['item3', '3'],
  ['item4', '4'],
  [' '],
  ['list2'],
  ['item1', '1'],
  ['item2', '2'],
  ['item3', '3'],
  ['item4', '4'],
  [' '],
  ['list3'],
  ['item1', '1'],
  ['item2', '2'],
  ['item3', '3'],
  ['item4', '4'],
  [' ']
];

var result = {};
var lastList = null;
for (var item of data) {
  if (item.length == 1 && item[0] != ' ') {
    result[item[0]] = lastList = {};
  }

  else if (lastList != null && item.length == 2) {
    lastList[item[0]] = item[1];
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Should the second `if` be `else if`?

Comment: Yep this does the trick. Its certainly more understandable than the previous answer.  The only issues is that my list names and item names will likely be different. i.e. they won't start with 'list' and 'item'

Comment: @user1513388 Does the edited solution work? If not, show us your real data, or describe it.

Comment: Change `==`  to be `===`

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the whole array by using a closure over a reference to the last object with the given key.

```js
var data = [['list1'], ['item1', '1'], ['item2', '2'], ['item3', '3'], ['item4', '4'], [' '], ['list2'], ['item1', '1'], ['item2', '2'], ['item3', '3'], ['item4', '4'], [' '], ['list3'], ['item1', '1'], ['item2', '2'], ['item3', '3'], ['item4', '4'], [' ']],
    result = data.reduce(function (ref) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (1 in a) {
                ref[a[0]] = a[1];
            } else if (a[0].trim()) {
                r[a[0]] = {};
                ref = r[a[0]]
            }
            return r;
        };
    }(undefined), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I get a type error `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1' in undefined` on the `if (1 in a)` line if I try this.

Comment: @user1513388, it works even in IE11, where do you get the error from?

Comment: I'm using nodeJS